# OSM data slightly distorted (flat projection)

Tags: latitude-longitude, openstreetmap

I've imported some OSM data into a 3D application, but the coordinates seem to be slightly distorted in the longitude axis compared to the map rendering on the OSM website.

[image: OSM Screenshot]
[image: 3D App Screenshot]

I've "translated" the Latitude and Longitude values into X/Z coordinates as is. Is there some special value that I need to multiply with the longitude value to get rid of the stretch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention how you "translated" lat/lon into x/y but I guess you are just using a different [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection).

Raw OSM data is projected in [*EPSG:4326* aka *WGS84*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System). OSM's [slippy map](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_Map) uses [*EPSG:3857* aka *Web Mercator* projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator). The [slippy map tilenames](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) wiki page provides some additional information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From what I gathered and with a little trial&error I figured dividing the longitude by `PI / 2` yields pretty accurate results.